# Convert UITextField to comma separated number and back to dot separator

Tags: ios, swift

Hello mighty StackOverflowers,

I know that this is a question surely more than a hundred times but I'm just at this stage as a total beginner (Swift 4 / Xcode 9) where I have absolutely no clue how to implement all these hints and things I have discovered, yet.

I guess this one ist boringly simple so here's my nerve pain:

I'm creating a little App for percentages. All works fine... as long as I don't touch the comma on the num pad of my iPhone set to German language since the calculation only works with dot separators.

At the beginning I want the UITextField to be converted to a dot-separated Integer/Float and to give the result I'd like to transform it back to a comma-seperated number.
Short: input with comma-separator, calculate with dot-separator, "print" result showing comma-separator.

Here's the code that's currently working as long as the Phone is set to English or (if German) only non-decimal numbers are added to the fields:

Oh... and one important thing: I failed badly to add the code snippets I have found here so far to my ViewController.swift... I just don't know where to put these lines :(
Here we go:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //User Fields:

    @IBOutlet weak var kind: UITextField!      // kind of unit (€, $, metres...)
    @IBOutlet weak var base: UITextField!      //base
    @IBOutlet weak var percent: UITextField!   //percent (1%, 4,5% etc.)

    //Result Labels:

    @IBOutlet weak var percentInKind: UILabel!   //the percent as value in kind
    @IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!           //base minus percentInKind 

    //Calculation:

    @IBAction func calculateTotal(_ sender: Any) {


        let kindConv = String(kind.text!)          //Converted to String
        let baseConv = Double(base.text!)          //Converted to Double
        let percentConv = Double(percent.text!)    //Converted to Double

        let percentInKindConv = Double(baseConv! * percentConv!) / 100

        percentInKind.text = String(format: "%.2f", percentInKindConv) + " \(kindConv)"
        total.text = String(format: "%.2f", baseConv! - percentInKindConv) + " \(kindConv)"
    }
```

Comment: Hint - Use `NumberFormatter` to convert to/from a user presented/entered string.

Comment: Thanks, @maddy. I have found a lot of 'NumberFormatter' mentions here but never found one to cover exactly this case. I've bought that German 1,300 pages Swift 4 Book and I'll learn about NumberFormatter now :D

Comment: I keep getting error messages... can't convert string into NumberFormatter, can't convert Double.... convert Float... nothing. I just don't get it :(

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code.

Comment: Hm... that's my problem I guess. There are two things I don't get it the way I want it. The first thing is that the App crashes with the German Number Pad because there's a comma instead of a point. So I want the app to convert the comma "," to a "." so that the calculation in the button works. And after the calculation I want it to be displayed in the label with the ",". I don't really know which part of the code above is the relevant part because I don't know where exactly these conversions have to be made.

Comment: Ha! Finally managed to use NumberFormatter to give the correct format (12,34 instead of 12.34) to the label.text. Next: use the extension which is always linked to this challenge. Only thing left is to prevent the app from crashing when using the German keyboard with comma separator. Will post the correct code as soon as it works (awaiting countless optimization postings to show me that I‘m a beginner, haha)

Answer (score 0):

0.05pm and the alarm goes off at 5.30am but I couldn't let this Sunday end without figuring out this hell of a beginner's problem. So I hope this code - which works for me - is correct and "clean". I'll just paste the whole thing to show people searching for it. I'd really appreciate further hints on shortening or "easing" this. So... here we go:

```
 //User input fields

    @IBOutlet weak var kind: UITextField!                //kind of unit (€, metres etc.)
    @IBOutlet weak var base: UITextField!                //base number
    @IBOutlet weak var percent: UITextField!             //percent in %

    //Result labels

    @IBOutlet weak var sumPercent: UILabel!              //% in kind of unit
    @IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!                   //base - sumPercent

    //Calculation

    @IBAction func berechnenAbziehen(_ sender: Any) {


        let kindVar = String(kind.text!)

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_DE")
        formatter.decimalSeparator = ","
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        let baseFormatter = formatter.number(from: base.text!) as! Double
        let percentFormatter = formatter.number(from: percent.text!) as! Double

        let percentSum = baseFormatter * percentFormatter / 100
        let totalSum = baseFormatter - percentSum

        sumPercent.text = formatter.string(for: percentSum)! + " \(kindVar)"
        total.text = formatter.string(for: totalSum)! + " \(kindVar)"
```

good night! ;-)